Help with inverse Z transform
I have the following function on time domain
$$f(t) = sin(100 * 2 * \pi * t)$$
and I need to get its discrete values when it's sampled at 1000Hz.
After applying the Z transform and using T = 1/1000, I got to the experession
$$F(z) = \frac{0.59 * z}{( z^2 - 1.62*z + 1)}$$
I'm failing to expand it to a partial fraction that can be transformed using table functions, or even to long divide it. Any help is appreciated.

You clearly have a zero at Z=0.  Apply your quadratic equation to find the poles.  (You'll get a matched complex pair of poles.)
